# unable to figure out why overlapped clustering is occuring

Tags: machine-learning, clustering, unsupervised-learning, dbscan

[image: DBSCAN CLUSTERING]

i am appling k means and DBSCAN to the same data set which is in csv format, but i'm unable to get good results. I have attached the DBSCAN results.I,m getting overlapped clusters and can't figure out why is that so. The dimensionality of my data set is 10+ and i have plotted 2D graphs .
When i did pre-processing i plotted some correlation plots on my raw data and found out that many of the attributes are having rectangular shaped graphs with one another, so i shifted to DBSCAN as i read somewhere that K-Means is good for spherical shaped datasets.
I'm new to this field of analytics so i'm unable to figure out why my clustering results are not good.
following graph is plotted without noise points.

Thanks

[image: DBSCAN clustering]

Comment: What exactly do the plots show? What is bad about those results?

Comment: You said your data has more than 10 dimensions, and this plot is 2-dimensional. This means it is just a 2d projection of your data. You may want to find the axes that separate more your data e.g with PCA and project datapoints along those axes.